# Grabbing all of the information from a tree type table

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to extract ids from a table that acts as a category tree. The two main columns in that table are the ID and the PARENT_ID.

The tricky part with this table is that the `ID` can also be the `PARENT_ID` for another `ID`.

I wanted to figure out a way to grab all of the IDs and PARENT_IDs under one "tree" but can only get a couple levels in.

Here's where I'm at:

```
 select * 
   from categories 
  where id = 2 
     or parent_id = 2 
     or parent in (select id  
                     from categories 
                    where parent_id = 2 
                       or parent_id = id)
```

Comment: Mysql doesnt have support for hierarchial queries,the only way is to self join as many times as you need.

Comment: @Mihai The ONLY way? Are you sure? Seems to me that there might be more ways.

Comment: @Strawberry AFAIK I should have added

Comment: @Mihai yeah turns out there wasn't a way around what I needed. But thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I've done something similar to this, but you'll need an extra column in your table, which is a concatenation of the all of its parents up the tree. The table would look like:

```
ID:   ParentID:  ID2:
1     1          1
2     1          1_2
3     1          1_3
4     1_2        1_2_4
5     1_3        1_3_5
6     1_3_5      1_3_5_6
```

The parentID doesn't necessarily have to be the concatenated parent ID, but I find that most useful. ID2 is the complete information of where the item is in the tree. If you want all of the branches below a single point, the query is easy:

```
select * from `table` where id2 like '1\_2\_%';
```

will give you all of the items underneath the id2='1_2' item.

Comment: A good suggestion, but unfortunately I don't have the ability to create a new column, so I had to do it the old fashioned way. But thanks for the suggestion!